# Jquery Raty Form PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, raty

I'm using [jQuery raty](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty) for a personal website.
I have a form and raty generates the following for each set of stars

```
<input type="hidden" name="score" value="5">
```

where value contains the values I want to get.

I have 10 fields with 5 stars each, and I want to get all 10 ratings with PHP/POST to insert into database.

What do I do about the fact that the inputs have the same name?
I am aware that if it was name="score[]" I could access the ratings in an array, but I don't think I can change the name that raty assigns to inputs

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change raty's names this should help you

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="score" value="5"> 
<input type="hidden" name="score" value="5"> 
<input type="hidden" name="score" value="5">
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(){
      var score;
      $('input[name="score"]').each(function(index) {
        //YOUR LOGIC
        //IE: score = $(this).val(); console.log(score);
        //IE: POPULATE hidden submit form or store for AJAX call

      });          

});
```

But if you can add a class it would probably be better practice to do

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" class='score' name="score" value="5"> 
<input type="hidden" class='score' name="score" value="5"> 
<input type="hidden" class='score' name="score" value="5">
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(){
      var score;
      $('.score').each(function(index) {
        //YOUR LOGIC
        //IE: score = $(this).val(); console.log(score);
      });

});
```

Or play with a parent div id and the `child()` method

Comment: actually, i think I might have just found a simpler solution. it appears that I can add an argument {scoreName   : 'name[]',} and then i should be able to access my ratings with $_POST['name'][0] etc...

Comment: Yeah if raty allows it that simpler indeed

Comment: i'll see if i can get what i mentioned to work, otherwise your answer is very specific thank you!